# How to add records in bulk into a SharePoint List which contains metadata columns?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have exported my SharePoint list to Excel. Some of the List columns contain metadata columns. Like: Created, Created By, Modified, Modified By. Now I want to restore the data from Excel back to my List again. But it seems I can not restore the data to the metadata columns. Is there a way to  restore the data from Excel to my metadata columns?

Greetings,

P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to import data from excel into metadata columns such as "Created", "Created By", "Modified", "Modified By". Values of these metadata columns are automatically created by SharePoint.

Comment: Well you can export a list that contains metadata columns. The problem is importing it back.

Comment: Sorry to write wrong. What I want to answer is that I don't think it's possible to import data from excel into metadata columns such as "Created", "Created By", "Modified", "Modified By". Values of these metadata columns are automatically created by SharePoint.